# Laravel 5.2 - Updating multiple rows with one query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I do a lot of calculations and at the end I have rates that need to be saved to existing rows in a table.

The array I have will be similar to the following:

```
[
    <model_id> => [
        'rate' => <some rate>
    ]
    <model_id_2> => [
        'rate' => <some other rate>
    ]
    .....
]
```

Now obviously I could foreach through this array and do an update for each and every item in the array but I could end up with 100 update calls. Is there a way (through laravel's eloquent OR even a raw sql query) to do all these updates through one call?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use a raw query with MySQL's `CASE` command, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449247/how-to-make-update-query-with-parameters-and-case-statement-in-laravel-4

Comment: Any chance you could write out an example? Table name is `pn_pensioner_member_yearly_summary`.... the primary key (that matches `<model_id>`) is `member_yearly_summary_id`. I wouldn't use this because it would literally mean making a sql query with 100 case checks....which seems a bit ridiculous...

Comment: Well, there's an example in that link. I agree that it's tedious and impractical at best, but MySQL doesn't have very good support for updating lots of things with lots of different values depending on things at the same time. As far as I'm aware, I'm afraid neither does Eloquent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are worried about the request spent time you can handle this by firing an event and then queueing your listener/job, who will save your model, so it can be processed asynchronously. For examples, go to [Laravel Docs for Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues)

As long as I know you cannot update multiple rows on Laravel.

Comment: I actually set it up as a queue job and its running relatively fast (less than a second for 100 records) so I will do this. Thanks!

Comment: Just to update people: you can update multiple rows using @NikunjK's answer.

Comment: @user3494047 yes, you can update multiple records through a single query, but with the SAME value. OP's question is to update multiple records with DIFFERENT values through one query.

Answer (score 7):

You may try with Eloquent `update()` for multiple records update. Here is some code which I am using for update multiple records into the my table.

```
\App\Notification::where('to_id', '=', 0)
                ->update(['is_read' => 1]);
```